# Start a Pythonscript in a Screen session

Tags: linux, bash, python-3.x, shell, gnu-screen

i am currently working on a little bash script to start a .py file in a Screen session and could use help.

I have these 2 Files:

**test.py (located at /home/developer/Test/):**

```
import os

print("test")
os.system("ping -c 5 www.google.de>>/home/developer/Test/test.log")
```

**test.sh (located at /home/developer/):**

```
#!/bin/bash

Status="NULL"

if ! screen -list | grep -q "foo";
    then
        Status="not running"
    else
        Status="running"
fi

echo "Status: $Status"

read -p "Press [Enter] key to start/stop."

if [[ $Status == "running" ]]
    then
        screen -S foo -p 0 -X quit
        echo "Stopped Executing"
    elif [[ $Staus == "not running" ]]
        then
            screen -dmS foo sh
            screen -S foo -X python /home/developer/Test/test.py
            echo "Created new Instance"
    else
        exit 1
fi
```

It works as intendet until it has to start the python script aka. this line:

```
screen -S foo -X python /home/developer/Test/test.py
```

when running it in my normal shell i get:

```
test
sh: 1: cannot create /home/developer/Test/test.log: Permission denied
```

**MY Questions:**

1. I understand the cause of the Permission denied case (works with sudo) but how do i give Permissions and more interestingly, to whom do i give the Permissions to? (python? | screen? | myuser?)
2. Is the line to create a new instance in which the script runs correct like that?
3. Can u think of a better way to execute a python script which has to run night and day but is start and stoppable and doesn't block the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You should not need to use sudo at all if the proper user/group is set on the scripts.

> ```
> $ chmod 644 <user> <group> <script name>
> ```

2. The line creating the new instance does not look correct, it should be more like:

> ```
> screen -S foo -d -m /usr/bin/python /home/Developer/Test/test.py
> ```
>
> While using full path to the python exec; remove useless preceding line: `screen -dmS foo sh`

3. Screen is more than adequte to prefer such tasks.

**Other problems in your script:**

1. Add a shebang to the python script (eg. `#!/usr/bin/python`)
2. Typo on line 20 of test.sh: should be `$Status`, not `$Staus`
3. You may need to initially create test.log before executing your script (eg. `touch test.log`)